# dispatch_once in super class?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

If I call `dispatch_once` inside an instance method of a super class, will it execute once for each subclass? I'm guessing not because the Xcode Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference says it "executes a block object once and only once for the lifetime of an application."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reading of the documentation is correct. That block will execute only once, provided you are using the same once token.

Answer (score 3):

Your reading of the documentation is almost correct:  dispatch_once() will execute only once for the lifetime of a given dispatch_once_t variable.  Since most applications declare this variable as a static global, the documentation covers this pattern.  If you have a token which is unique for each class instance and starts out properly zero-initialized, then it will execute for each instance.